# Exchange users moved mailbox now can't open some calendars

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, exchange, outlook, calendar

OK So the environment is Exchange sp on Windows 2003 server.
This weekend we had to move a bunch of users of off one information store that was corrupt and onto a temp store delete the original dodgy store and then move the users back from the temp store to one of the three other stores under the same original storage group.

Since then we are having some weird access issues relating to calendars. I am assuming it is all related, but it might not be.

The problem is that users are unable to see any calendars that they have previously had access to. The weird thing is, that some of the users in question are not ones who have been moved nor are they trying to access calendars that belong to people whose accounts have been moved. Hence my assumption its related but possibly not.

The message received is "Unable to display the folder. The calendar folder could not be found."

here is the kicker, if i move someone who is trying to access other calendars, to a different mailbox store (thereby creating a new email account and sending stuff over), things start to work again. this to me indicates a permissions problem however I am unsure in what way.

Looking for help out there please guys :)

Cheers

Comment: Looking at it - it would appear just users on one store are affected.

Answer (score 1):

When you move mailboxes, Microsoft recommends that you also move any mailboxes that are delegates of the mailboxes that you're moving. Say Alice is the big boss and Bob is her assistant; Bob has delegate access to Alice's mailbox. If you move Alice, but not Bob, you'll see the behavior that you're reporting.

You should also check to make sure the default public folder store is correctly set for all stores that hold users.